# telerik radGrid custom filter and exporting to excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

In my case I use custom filter method. I have my own dropdowns and so on to choose appropriate data then I filter my dataSource call rebind and as a result I can see only filtered rows.

That works fine.

Here is the sample code:

```
 private void BindGrid()
    {
        var dataSource = AllOrdersReports;

        Grd.DataSource = dataSource;
        Grd.Rebind();
    }
```

The problem is that When I then push the button with code:

```
Grd.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

All records are exported to excel despite the fact that right now there are only filtered records in the grid.

Any ideas why it behaves like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem solved figured ot that I had also onDataSource needed event handler implemented...